# How to store large timeseries objects in a relational database?

Tags: database, relational-database, time-series

The timeseries-object timestamps are non regular. Ticks are in seconds. Crucial data are in the past 10 days, so these data should be accessed very fast and must be presented in a real-time html/js chart (chart will auto update through asynchronous requests). Data more than 10 days should be stored, too, but can be in some zipped form (blob? file? what?).

For each user I might need millions of entries of data each year. So, my problem is (a) scalability, (b) ease and speed to open the timeseries and compute statistics (median values, etc). We decided that the user will be able to view real-time timestamped values for the past 10 days only.

For the project we will be using django and python/pandas library.

Comment: Have you looked at time-series databases? I wonder why it has to be relational. Is it because of db client connection requirement, i.e. sometimes the application developers want to use jdbc/odbc only.

Comment: I am using python/django. Can you suggest some?

Comment: There are several lists out there, but you might want to look at this list. It has a brief summary for each entry: http://www.erol.si/2015/01/the-complete-list-of-all-timeseries-databases-for-your-iot-project/

Answer (score 0):

We deal with tick data using PostgreSQL. 
In order to keep queries fast, we partition the tables first by date, and then also alphabetically (instruments starting with letters A-B-C-D in one partition, E-F-G-H in another...)
Adding indices on the timestamps, and ticker-id, as well as regular VACUUM cleaning and clustering of the tables at the end of day... also helps, but partitions give the single biggest increase in performace, by far.